# Webpack Laravel-Mix Chunk error TypeError: "e[r] is undefined"

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Am building a web application with Vue and Laravel.
Am utilizing code splitting and versioning with Laravel mix and Webpack under the hood.

However, whenever i make changes to my code, run npm run production and upload on the live server, on frequent occations i receive TypeError: "e[r] is undefined"

[image: Screenshot]

I have to manually clear browser cache before the page loads correctly.
I already have versioning enabled and thus cache busting should be automated.

Below is my webpack.mix.js file

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const webpack = require('webpack');
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
    ]
})
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [new CompressionPlugin()],
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        namedModules: true,
        namedChunks: true,
        removeAvailableModules: true,
        flagIncludedChunks: true,
        occurrenceOrder: false,
        usedExports: true,
        concatenateModules: true,
        sideEffects: false, // <----- in prod defaults to true if left blank
    }
};

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/main/main.js', 'public/v1.4.0/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .extract(['vue'])
    .version();
```

Comment: run `npm run dev` when you see the error again try to check which line causing this problem

Comment: It's all ok in development mode. And its ok in production mode ONLY IF i clear cache or force a hard reload

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a solution that wasn't quite good but it worked: set in webpack config options `optimization.concatenateModules` and `optimization.minimize` to false.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of hustle,

my best approach was to control cache from the server software itself.

Ex: you can prevent JS and CSS caching from nginx / apache/http configurations